# how to validate two joi schema objects

Tags: node.js, npm, joi

I have two **users** `customer` and `manager`. `manager` has some extra fields in its schema. So for that i have created two joi schema objects:

1. validating common schema (for customer and manager) and
2. validating some extra fields for manager.

For the `manager` validation i have to validate both the joi schema objects.

```
const commonSchema = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().min(3).max(255).required(),
    email: Joi.string().email().required(),
    password: Joi.string().min(3).max(15).required(),
    ...
  }).options({ allowUnknown: true });

const managerSchema = Joi.object({
    contactNumber: Joi.string()
      .length(10)
      .pattern(/^[0-9]+$/)
      .required(),
    creditCardNum: Joi.string().length(16).required(),
    isApproved: Joi.boolean().default(false),
    ...
  }).options({ allowUnknown: true });
  
  const { errorOne } = commonSchema.validate(manager);
  const { errorTwo } = managerSchema.validate(manager);
```

This works but if there another way of validating both the schemas for `manager` and only commonSchema for `customer` without using `options.({ allowUnknown: true })`. Because i don't want to allow all unknown fields.

Comment: You're defining this with code, can't you just use the same object you pass to `Joi.object()` twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple & easy solution will be to define the common fields as fields and not as `joi object`.

please notice that in my code the `...` means spread operator.

```
      const commonSchemaFields = {
        name: Joi.string().min(3).max(255).required(),
        email: Joi.string().email().required(),
        password: Joi.string().min(3).max(15).required(),
      };
    
      const managerSchemaFields = {
        ...commonSchemaFields,
        contactNumber: Joi.string()
          .length(10)
          .pattern(/^[0-9]+$/)
          .required(),
        creditCardNum: Joi.string().length(16).required(),
        isApproved: Joi.boolean().default(false),
      };
    
      const commonSchema = Joi.object({...commonSchemaFields}).options({ allowUnknown: true });
      const managerSchema = Joi.object({...managerSchemaFields}).options({ allowUnknown: true })

 
      const { errorOne } = commonSchema.validate(manager);
      const { errorTwo } = managerSchema.validate(manager);
```